# How do you authenticate the GraphQL endpoint in Postman?

Tags: sitecore-api, graphql

I am getting 403 "Authentication required." when i hit the GraphQL query in Postman.
I am able to execute the same query in Sitecore GraphQL Playground.

In postman, i am passing the URL as `https://{domain}/sitecore/api/graph/items/master?sc_apikey=key value`

Also, Tried with using basic authentication with user name and password since Sitecore is using IDS for authentication.

How to make the authentication successful via postman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can authenticate by generating `bearer token` using postman as explain by Dan. http://www.dansolovay.com/2023/01/using-postman-to-authenticate-to-graphql.html

one more alternative is you can set `requireAuthentication` to `false` with the patch while using postman.

1. Go to file AppConfig\Sitecore\Services.GraphQL\Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.config
2. set `<requireAuthentication>false</requireAuthentication>`

More details: https://singhajit.com/how-to-integrate-graphql-with-sitecore-using-jss/

I tried an alternative approach and it works well.
[image]
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Sumit Helaiya. I was tryin with the first option to get and use bearer token by following the same post. But i was facing some issues. Your second option works fine for me. Almost i have done everything as you have. Mistake what i was doing is i have enabled both requireAuthentication and requireApiKey. Thank you.